# PHP/AJAX Live logins log

Tags: php, html, ajax, reload, updating

Basically, when the user logins, I need a separate web page automatically updating each log in, for example:

12:30 User1 have logged in.
12:35 User5 have logged in.

etc. etc.

I want the page to update itself all the time.
How can I achieve this simply?

@Edit
Yes, I know about Ajax, but I mean generally how to do it.
When the user logins, shall I write into HTML each log line by line and then use Ajax to keep reloading it?

Comment: with jQuery / AJAX :) Try to google "AJAX post/get request without page reloading" or something like that and I hope, that you will find what you are looking for ==> [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Try with jquery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

When a user logs in, you append a string to a file using PHP.

Now create a PHP file called **ajaxCalls.php** and from there you have to open the file and echo out every row.(be sure to encode this output as json, it becomes easier to work with in javascript).
Now call **ajaxCalls.php**(using AJAX) and fetch the result as a a json object from the page you want the strings below to be shown on.

```
12:30 User1 have logged in.
12:35 User5 have logged in.
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    $username = "foo";
    $password = "bar";
    if(userCanLogin($username, $password))
    {
        saveToFile($username);
    }

    function saveToFile($username)
    {
        $fileHandle = fopen("userLogins.txt", "a");
        fwrite(date("H:i") . " " . $username . " has logged in.", $fileHandle);
        fclose($fileHandle);
    }
?>
```

**index.php** *The page you want the to update automaticly*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>

            function getUserLogins()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: json
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(result);
                        for(var row in jsonObject)
                        {
                            $("#userLogins").append(row);
                        }
                    }
                });
                setTimeout(getUserLogins, 1000); 
            }
            $(function() {
                getUserLogins();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="userLogins"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php** *This file is should only be called asynchronous*

```
<?php
    $lines = file("userLogins.txt");
    echo json_encode($lines);
?>
```

All of the code above is untested!
If you want **instant** updates, you have to setup a service that "pushes" the data to you, instead of "pulling".
When pushing is performed, the client acts like a receiver which is sent from a server. The then have to use some sort of sockets, like WebSockets to handle the data. You can either use a "push" provider like http://beaconpush.com/ or create your own push server(NodeJS is recommended).